# What's the recommended workaround if numeric_limits<double>::has_infinity is false?

Tags: c++, linux, double, limit, infinity

I need to check a double value for infinity in a C++ app on Linux. On most platforms this works by comparing with `std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()`. However, on some old platforms (RedHat 9 for example, with gcc 3.2.2) this is not available, and `std::numeric_limits<double>::has_infinity` is false there.

What workaround would you recommend for those platforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have now resorted to using the `INFINITY` and `NAN` macros on that particular machine - seems to work fine. They come from `math.h`.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using IEEE 754 arithmetic, as you almost certainly are, infinities are well defined values and have defined outcomes for all arithmetic operations.  In particular,

```
infinity - infinity = NaN
```

Positive and negative infinity and `NaN` values are the only values for which this is true.  NaNs are special "not-a-number" values used to indicate domain errors of functions, e.g. `sqrt(-1)`.  Also:

```
NaN != NaN
```

`NaN`s are the only values for which this is true.

Therefore:

```
bool is_infinite(double x) {
    double y = x - x;
    return x == x && y != y;
}
```

will return true if and only if `x` is either positive or negative infinity.  Add a test for `x > 0` if you only want to check for positive infinity.

Comment: std::numeric_limits<double>::has_infinity==false suggests you do NOT have IEEE 754

Comment: That may be true, but in the OP's case it's likely to mean he has an incomplete C++ Standard Library implementation that **has** IEEE 754 but doesn't "realise it".  Why?  Because IEEE 754 is usually done in hardware, and upgrading to a newer compiler fixed the problem.

Comment: But I agree that in the general case, if you do not know otherwise, then you should assume that std::numeric_limits<double>::has_infinity==false implies no IEEE 754.

Answer (score 1):

For most cases, std::numeric_limits::max() can be a valid replacement for std::numeric_limits::infinity().

You would have to be more careful about using it, however. With overflows I believe you would have to manually detect the overflow and set the result to the max explicitly if an overflow is detected.